# objective-c iPhone address book : kABPersonAddressStreetKey

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

I'm getting the Address Book `kABPersonAddressStreetKey` property. When there are multiple streets, values are concatenated into one string.

```
[addressDict setObject:self.address.street1 forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
```

Sometimes I would like to change this property with a new streets names... How to do that when there is more than one street ?

Example of the problem :

```
= Address1
=== StreetName1
=== StreetName2
=> 2 streets names

get the line : "StreetName1 StreetName2"
changes in streets names...
save the line will change the address to

= Address1
=== StreetName3 StreetName4
=> 1 street name

but i want

= Address1
=== StreetName3
=== StreetName4
=> 2 streets names
```

I Hope I'm clear enough...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use \n to separate addresses. So, for example:

```
NSString *addresses = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", self.address.street1, self.address.street2];
[addressDict setObject:addresses forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this ;-)

Comment: Excellent, this works and is something that has been annoying me for a few months now.  Thank you.